# Use the requirejs module without importing it with node

Tags: javascript, python, requirejs, require, child-process

I want to run a python file from javascript, and have determined the easiest way to do it is to use 'spawn'...however, I need to use require('child_process'). I really need help in gettng this to work, without using npm in the terminal.

```js
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/child_process@1.0.2/index.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.6/minified/require.js"></script>

<script>
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const childPython = spawn('python',['python.py', data]);

childPython.stdout.on('data',(data)=>{console.log('stdout:', data)});

childPython.stderr.on('data',(data)=>{console.log('stderr:', data)});

childPython.on('data',(code)=>{console.log('process closed with:', code)});
</script>
```

Comment: You can't run a child process via spawn in client side JavaScript. That you can only do in NodeJs. You will need to build a server side script that one can trigger from the browser to run a script

Comment: Would *you* want arbitrary JavaScript executed in your browser to be able to spawn any executable it wants?

Answer (score 0):

This won't work on the client-side. But you can achieve what you want by making a request to the server-side to run the specific python code and return the result in the response. Then you can console.log it on the client-side.

Comment: True.  But require() is used in a lot of other processes...like a web of dependancies.  It would be beneficial figure out how to use it...especially if you prefer a python server.  I am using apache2 (simple).  The goal is not running python, but getting require() to work without node.

Comment: I was able to get python to work on apache2 by enabling cgi on the server: